# Amplitude of eliptically polarised light

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

In elliptically polarized light, can one define something called amplitude of Electric field? If yes, how do we determine it?

Comment: Yes, see the mathematical description of elliptically polarized light from Wiki, which labels the "amplitude" as $|{\mathbf{E}}|$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_polarization

Comment: In such a case, how do we determine direction of major axis of the ellipse from any of the standard basis vectors directions?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you use the amplitude $|\mathbf E|$ of the electric field to find the total amount of energy carried by the electromagnetic wave; the root-mean-square magnitude of the [Poynting vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector) for an EM plane wave is
$$
\left< S \right> = \frac{\epsilon_0 c}2 |\mathbf E|^2
.
$$

You seem to be after a way to specify the degree of [elliptical polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_polarization), which is a little bit different.

Elliptical polarization requires light to have two different plane polarization states with a specific relative phase between them. To find the long axis of your polarization ellipse, you would put a plane polarizer between your light source and your light detector.  You'll see the maximum transmission $I_\text{max}$ when the polarizer is parallel to the long axis of the ellipse, and the minimum transmission $I_\text{min}$ when the polarizer is parallel to the short axis of the ellipse.  The *linear* polarization of the beam is therefore 
$$
P_\text{linear} = \frac{I_\text{max}-I_\text{min}}{I_\text{max}+I_\text{min}}
$$
and the partial amplitudes $I_\text{max,min}$ are related the parameters $a,b$ of the polarization ellipse.

Notice that circularly polarized light has zero *linear* polarization, since its polarization ellipse has $a=b$, but is different from *unpolarized* light because the phase between the two components is coherent. To distinguish between circular-polarized light and unpolarized light, you repeat the test above with [circular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarizing_filter_%28Photography%29) rather than linear polarizers. (However a circular-polarizing filter is usually a [quarter-wave](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/quarwv.html) plate or film in front of a linear polarizer.) Elliptically polarized light will exhibit both nonzero linear and nonzero circular polarization.